# Making a text field required if the value of a radio is a specified value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with radio buttons and a text field.  How can I make the text field manditory if the selected radio's value is 96 or 97. My code so far is below

```
<p style="margin: 0px 4px 1px 4px;padding: 4px 0 4px 0; background:#FFF"><input type="radio" name="qID18" value="96" class="required" />  All Festivals / Events  </p>

<p style="margin: 0px 4px 1px 4px;padding: 4px 0 4px 0; background:#FFF"><input type="radio" name="qID18" value="97" class="required" />  Similar Festivals / Events  </p>

<p style="margin: 0px 4px 1px 4px;padding: 4px 0 4px 0; background:#FFF"><input type="radio" name="qID18" value="98" class="required" />  No thank you  </p>

<p style="margin: 0px 4px 1px 4px;padding: 4px 0 4px 0; background:#FFF">&nbsp; Enter Email To Send Information To: <input type="text" name="something" ></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('input[name="qID18"]').change(function(){
   if (this.value == 96 || this.value == 97) {
      $('input[name="something"]').addClass('required')
   } else {
      $('input[name="something"]').removeClass('required')
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    var radio = $(":radio:checked").val();
    if (radio == 96 || radio == 97) {
        if ($.trim($(":text").val()) == "") {
            alert("Failed!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a form element containing these input elements?  If so, just add a submit handler  that checks the value and applies or removes the required attribute as desired.  I've adding a form container around your mark-up and added a submit button as well and posted my solution on jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/quant/2pJkc/

Comment: Note: my solution uses the "required" attribute on the input tag, which is not supported by IE.  However, the code can be easily modified to make it use another method to require the text field.  It seemed like your question was mainly asking where to start. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp You might also want to check out the "aria-required" attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
var radiobuttonchecked = $(":radio:checked").val();
if (radiobuttonchecked !=98 ) {
    if ($.trim($(":text").val()) == '') {
        alert('text is mandatory.');
        return false;
    }
}
```